# Error creating a list of key values pairs in R

Tags: r, list, keyvaluepair

I am trying to create a list of paired values like so:

```
> prot_keys<-snp.ids_mrna
> prot_vals<-seq.aa
> mylist<-list()
> mylist[[ prot_keys ]] <- prot_vals
```

where:

```
> dput(seq.aa)
c("MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKSPMLNLFQEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
"MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKGPV", 
"MDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ", 
"MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ"
)
> dput(snp.ids_mrna)
c("NM_001146040", "XM_005268412", "NM_001292000", "NM_000171"
)
```

and both objects are of type "character".

The error message I am getting in:

```
> mylist[[ prot_keys ]] <- prot_vals
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, prot_keys, value = c("MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTSGYDARIRPNFKGPPVNVSCNIFINSFGSIAETTMDYRVNIFLRQQWNDPRLAYNEYPDDSLDLDPSMLDSIWKPDLFFANEKGAHFHEITTDNKLLRISRNGNVLYSIRITLTLACPMDLKNFPMDVQTCIMQLESFGYTMNDLIFEWQEQGAVQVADGLTLPQFILKEEKDLRYCTKHYNTGKFTCIEARFHLERQMGYYLIQMYIPSLLIVILSWISFWINMDAAPARVGLGITTVLTMTTQSSGSRASLPKVSYVKAIDIWMAVCLLFVFSALLEYAAVNFVSRQHKELLRFRRKRRHHKSPMLNLFQEDEAGEGRFNFSAYGMGPACLQAKDGISVKGANNSNTTNPPPAPSKSPEEMRKLFIQRAKKIDKISRIGFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ",  : 
  no such index at level 1
```

But I do not understand what this error message is telling me. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think dictionaries/keyvaluepairs in R work like that with vectors. The following code works, but it's definitely not nice. I haven't found a way to do this with `lapply` though.

```
for (i in 1:length(prot_keys)){
  mylist[[prot_keys[i]]]=prot_vals[i]
}
```

Comment: ok, so just looking at the result - how do I access the key? I can access the value by doing mylist[i][[1]]. However I need to be able to access the key for each element

Comment: To access the key by value you can use this function:
names(mylist[which(mylist=="GFPMAFLIFNMFYWIIYKIVRREDVHNQ[...]")]). To access the first key (or loop through) use: names(mylist[1])

Comment: ok thanks this is great. I actually subbed in "GFPMAF...." for mylist[1][[1]] to get first element. it produced the same result